# Remove AD users from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, profiles

I'm trying to remove all users from one specific OU in AD from our **SharePoint 2010 farm**.
I have change the Synchronization Connections, so it does not include the specific OU any more. 
First I **tried to run Profile Sync to see what happened**, and to me it seems like nothing changed. **All users are still there**.
Then I deleted the users with use of the web GUI "Manage User Profiles", and ran a profile sync once more. But still all the users are there.

When I **deleted** the users and then searched for them, they where gone, but **after a Profile Sync, they were all back in the system**.

**What am I missing out on here?**

I can't delete the users from the OU in AD as they still need other services we run, but they shall not have access to our SharePoint farm.

Any help is greatly appreciated.